# GcmTaskService may be blocking Exact Target push service

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

We have a service which extends GcmTaskService and declared that as a service in an AndroidManifest as

```
<service
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

When i have this service Exact Target EtPush Service doesn't post the registration event but when i remove this service the registration works so i am assuming that our service is blocking your ETPushService which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

ETPushService extends GcmReceiver (by Google).  In GcmReceiver there is code that looks for services and executes against the service found at index 0.  I have filed a bug report for this, but there is no fix.

**Workaround:**

Manually define the ETPushService in your manifest and ensure it appears before any other service.

```
<service
    android:name="com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.etsdk.ETPushService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This will not affect any of your other services as this will only be called when a push message is received.

Comment: Okay i added this service but seems like my app now crashes with exception

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.etsdk.ETPushService

Comment: Never mind the class name was wrong now its working thanks